# IOS, wireless or usb charging status

Tags: ios, uikit, uidevice

I would like to find out if it is possible to know if the iphone is charging from usb or wireless. I do develop for Android but not at all for IOS.
Therefore, i know it is possible on android to get this information from the [BatteryManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) but not on IOS.

I tried to find the equivalent on ios but i only found the [UIDeviceBatteryState](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevicebatterystate?language=objc).

The only constants are :

- UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown
- UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged
- UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging
- UIDeviceBatteryStateFull

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sorry you can't know that in IOS the only available properties regarding battery in the current `UIDevice` are [image]